# Bug lib jQueryGantt em página com bootstrap

Tags: jquery, laravel, bootstrap-3, bootstrap

Estou utilizando o plugin jQueryGantt (https://github.com/robicch/jQueryGantt) mas percebo que em páginas com bootstrap ele "buga" a tabela como na imagem abaixo, gostaria de saber se alguem ja utilizou essa lib e possa me ajudar.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Qual arquivo .css você está importando primeiro, o do Bootstrap ou do Plugin? Sua tabela tem a classe "table" do Bootstrap?

Comment: Tanto faz a ordem de importação o problema continua o mesmo e colocando ou não a classe "table"